# How do i remove middle word from string of 3 words?

Tags: java

```
String s;  //contains the main string i have to input
String s1; //is the set of the 1st and 3rd word
String st; //st is to get the 3 words separately
char c;
int i;
      int l=s.length();//l is for length of string
for(i=0;i<l;i++){
              c=s.charAt(i);
              if(c==' '){
                   if(st.equals("Middle")){
                   st="";
                   }
                   else{
                   s1=s1+" "+st;
                   st="";
                   }
              }
              else{st=st+c;}
    }
    System.out.println(s1);
```

I have spent 3 hours on this question but still cant debug why my code runs by outputting just the first word and leaves the rest 2 words when i only want it to leave the 2 word. I know how to run this program but this way is new and i dont know whats wrong

Comment: please provide an [mcve]

Comment: What are `l`, `st` and `c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split`. 
For instance if your string is "A String Example". Lets say you want to keep the word String then :

```
String[] array;
String txt = "A String Example";
String output;
array=txt.split(" "); // split the text using space.
output = array[1]; // if you want to keep the second word.
```

At this point your array contains: [A, String, Example]. Because your text got split wherever it contains space.  Then choose what word u like. if you want the middle word its array[1], etc.

Comment: Thanx.........I know this method.it is just the typical programmer in me who wants to know the error in the code in the question:)

Comment: Your code assuming that there is the word "Middle" in the input text. Why to do that.

Comment: Middle is just a sample to middle word of the string. I have to code this program by removing the middle word from a given string of 3 words.if middle word is ABC then i would use ABC instead of middle

Comment: So you know what to remove right? In that case you need th replace function. But  I know that you may not want to use that. So: In your program you do not reset the st variable. You just keep adding chars to eat assumi8ng that you have not constructed your wanted string yet. You do not code for the case that you are building a totally wrong string. You need to check when to reset your variable st. Again.. the best you got to do is to delete it and go with solutions provided already. You could save these three hours :)

Comment: Found it......... thanks a lotttt. I really cant type my happiness over the keyboard.i had to do this one thing-s=s+" "; and be done with it....